# Android data binding - how to use primitives in xml

Tags: android, data-binding

I have the following piece of xml in android and i am trying to use xml to demo a point. i want to use raw mathematics and depending on the outcome i will show a textview. For example:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="i am now visible"
            android:visibility="@{5*5 ==25 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>
```

this is clearly just for my personal education but can this be done ? or does it have to be in a class ?

right now im getting a build compiler error as its treating the entire thing as a resource type instead of a data binding.  Also in my gradle build file i have enabled data binding:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

The entire xml file if necessary looks like this and excuse the housekeeping, i just need to know why data binding is not working not the rest of the file. and the textview does appear in the view.

```
<LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/sample_main_layout">


            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="i am now visible"
                android:visibility="@{1==1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
               />


    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />



</LinearLayout>
```

I have a feeling i dont have data binding set up right ?  My gradle file has it enabled and then for the classpath i tried to do this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
    classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.+'
}
```

but gradle fails to sync stating that theres no classpath like this. the error is this:

```
 `Error:Unable to find method 'android.databinding.tool.LayoutXmlProcessor.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/databinding/tool/writer/JavaFileWriter;IZLandroid/databinding/tool/LayoutXmlProcessor$OriginalFileLookup;)V'.
```

I searched on line but i cant find the official way to enable databinding in android studio. I am on 2.0 of the IDE. `

Comment: Is this inside a layout resource with the `<layout>` root tag?

Comment: yes i updated the question. The layout itself works fine if i remove the databinding reference from the textview in the xml file.  To enable databinding i only have to set enabled =true in gradle right ? is there anything else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To enable databinding i only have to set enabled =true in gradle right ?

No, you also need to wrap your layouts, as covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#data_binding_layout_files), such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <data>

    <import type="android.text.Html"/>

    <variable
      name="question"
      type="com.commonsware.android.databind.basic.Question"/>
  </data>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/icon"
      android:layout_width="@dimen/icon"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/icon"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
      android:padding="8dip"
      app:error="@{@drawable/owner_error}"
      app:imageUrl="@{question.owner.profileImage}"
      app:placeholder="@{@drawable/owner_placeholder}"/>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="@{Html.fromHtml(question.title)}"
      android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/score"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
      android:text="@{Integer.toString(question.score)}"
      android:textSize="40sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"/>

  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

In your case, you would need the root `<layout>` tag, probably an empty `<data>` tag, and then your regular view hierarchy.

> I searched on line but i cant find the official way to enable databinding in android studio

There is nothing that needs to be "enabled" at the Android Studio level AFAIK. Certainly, I haven't enabled anything in my AS 1.5.1 installation, and data binding works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `Android Gradle` version!
If your `Android Gradle Tool` version is `2.0.0-alpha1` or higher, then may be this is the source of the error.
Because when I change the version to `1.5.0` then I get rid of the bug.
The [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) tells me `1.5.0-alpha1` or higher.
I do not know why I get the error when my version is higher too.
Please tell me if you know!

Answer (score 1):

> To enable databinding i only have to set enabled =true in gradle right
>   ?

Yes. With the new gradle 2.0.0 and Andorid Studio 2.0
I have only changed my app's gradle file by adding this -

```
android {
    ...

    dataBinding{
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

and it works like a charm.
There's no need to add `classpath'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.+'` in project's gradle file and no need to add `apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'`  in app's gradle file.